# Greek and English in lstlisting

Tags: babel, languages, greek

I'm trying to create an  lstlisting that contains both english and greek letters.

I have set this style.

```
\lstset{
      basicstyle=\normalsize\selectlanguage{english}\ttfamily,  % COURIER NEW?
    frame=tb, % draw a frame at the top and bottom of the code block
    tabsize=4, % tab space width
    showstringspaces=false, % don't mark spaces in strings
    numbers=left, % display line numbers on the left
    commentstyle=\color{black}, % comment color
    keywordstyle=\color{black}, % keyword color
    stringstyle=\color{black} % string color
}
```

and I want to include this code inside the lstlisting. As you can see there is greek text: 'Σύνθετη Αναζήτηση'. However when i run the pdfLatex compiler, it is rendered in latin character.

```
\begin{lstlisting}
<?php

function custom_toolbar_link($wp_admin_bar) {
    $args = array(
        'id' => 'advanced_search',
        'title' => 'Σύνθετη Αναζήτηση',
        'href' => 'admin.php?page=advanced-search',

        'meta' => array(
            'class' => 'advanced_search',
            'title' => 'advanced search'
        )
    );
    $wp_admin_bar->add_node($args);
}
add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'custom_toolbar_link', 10);
\end{lstlisting}
```

Can you help me?

*** A full minimal example of the text:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{dirtree}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chicago}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}

\lstset{
      basicstyle=\normalsize\selectlanguage{english}\ttfamily,  % COURIER NEW?
    frame=tb, % draw a frame at the top and bottom of the code block
    tabsize=4, % tab space width
    showstringspaces=false, % don't mark spaces in strings
    numbers=left, % display line numbers on the left
    commentstyle=\color{black}, % comment color
    keywordstyle=\color{black}, % keyword color
    stringstyle=\color{black} % string color
}

% This concludes the preamble
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[label=some-code,caption=Some Code]
<?php
function custom_toolbar_link($wp_admin_bar) {
    $args = array(
        'id' => 'advanced_search',
        'title' => 'Σύνθετη Αναζήτηση',
        'href' => 'admin.php?page=advanced-search',
        'meta' => array(
            'class' => 'advanced_search',
            'title' => 'advanced search'
        )
    );
    $wp_admin_bar->add_node($args);
}
add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'custom_toolbar_link', 10);
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) I know this does not compile, but you are much more likely to get help if you provide a full minimal example instead of sniplets.

Comment: Thank you, I just added a full minimal example of my text.

Comment: Can you use `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex`?  On my system, your example works well if I remove your `inputenc` line, and replace it with `\usepackage{fontspec}\setmonofont{Courier New}`, then compile with `xelatex`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but I would like to find a way using PDFLaTex. It is matter of compatibility with other files. Instead of article I use a custom class provided from my University, and xelatex doesn't work with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you can load any monospaced Unicode font through `fontspec` that contains Greek, such as New Computer Modern Mono or Libertinus Mono.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{newcomputermodern}
\usepackage{listings}

\babelprovide[import]{greek}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\normalsize\selectlanguage{english}\ttfamily,  % COURIER NEW?
    frame=tb, % draw a frame at the top and bottom of the code block
    tabsize=4, % tab space width
    showstringspaces=false, % don't mark spaces in strings
    numbers=left, % display line numbers on the left
    commentstyle=\color{black}, % comment color
    keywordstyle=\color{black}, % keyword color
    stringstyle=\color{black} % string color
}

% This concludes the preamble
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[label=some-code,caption=Some Code]
<?php
function custom_toolbar_link($wp_admin_bar) {
    $args = array(
        'id' => 'advanced_search',
        'title' => 'Σύνθετη Αναζήτηση',
        'href' => 'admin.php?page=advanced-search',
        'meta' => array(
            'class' => 'advanced_search',
            'title' => 'advanced search'
        )
    );
    $wp_admin_bar->add_node($args);
}
add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'custom_toolbar_link', 10);
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

You indicated in a comment that you wanted to use Courier New.  That would not be my recommendation, but if you do, you can add the lines

```
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmonofont{Courier New}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
```

If you are forced to use PDFLaTeX, the `listing` package does not support UTF-8, but might work with ISO-8859-7.  You may wish to use `selinput` to automatically detect the input encoding, so that a document saved as UTF-8 has a chance to compile.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{selinput} % Auto-detect input encoding.
\usepackage{textalpha} % Enable Greek text
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}

\SelectInputEncodingList{utf8, iso-8859-7}
\SelectInputMappings{ alpha=α }

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\normalsize\ttfamily,
    frame=tb, % draw a frame at the top and bottom of the code block
    tabsize=4, % tab space width
    showstringspaces=false, % don't mark spaces in strings
    numbers=left, % display line numbers on the left
    commentstyle=\color{black}, % comment color
    keywordstyle=\color{black}, % keyword color
    stringstyle=\color{black}, % string color
    extendedchars=false % listings does not support UTF-8.
}

% This concludes the preamble
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[label=some-code,caption=Some Code]
<?php
function custom_toolbar_link($wp_admin_bar) {
    $args = array(
        'id' => 'advanced_search',
        'title' => 'Σύνθετη Αναζήτηση'
        'href' => 'admin.php?page=advanced-search',
        'meta' => array(
            'class' => 'advanced_search',
            'title' => 'advanced search'
        )
    );
    $wp_admin_bar->add_node($args);
}
add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'custom_toolbar_link', 10);
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Another option is to use `minted`.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape to Latex. for example:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[label=some-code,caption=Some Code,escapeinside=;;]
<?php
function custom_toolbar_link($wp_admin_bar) {
$args = array(
'id' => 'advanced_search',
'title' => ';\selectlanguage{greek}Σύνθετη Αναζήτηση\selectlanguage{english};',
'href' => 'admin.php?page=advanced-search',
'meta' => array(
'class' => 'advanced_search',
'title' => 'advanced search'
)
);
$wp_admin_bar->add_node($args);
}
add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'custom_toolbar_link', 10);
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: Maybe `\textgreek{Σύνθετη Αναζήτηση}`? Didn't test, though.

Comment: This works too, as long as it is inside the escape characters.